# How to run docker successfully?

Tags: macos, docker, macos-mojave

I am trying to run the docker example here.

http://chembl.blogspot.com/2020/01/new-chembl-ligand-based-target.html

I can start the docker correctly.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 chembl/mcp:25
```

But when I run this

```
curl -X POST -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"smiles": "CC(=O)Oc1ccccc1C(=O)O"}' http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

I got these logging messages.

```
2020/03/26 13:21:38 Started logging stderr from function.
2020/03/26 13:21:39 Started logging stdout from function.
2020/03/26 13:21:39 OperationalMode: http
2020/03/26 13:21:39 Timeouts: read: 10s, write: 10s hard: 10s.
2020/03/26 13:21:39 Listening on port: 8080
2020/03/26 13:21:39 Writing lock-file to: /tmp/.lock
2020/03/26 13:21:39 Metrics listening on port: 8081
2020/03/26 13:24:53 Upstream HTTP request error: Post http://127.0.0.1:5000/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused
```

I use Mac OS X.

Does anybody know how to fix the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run into the same problem and managed to fix it. All I had to do was increase the resources on Docker Desktop for Mac OS X (the RAM, to be more specific). And also, wait a minute or two as it seems that the module loading is quite resource-intensive.